# How to modify and export files included in project?

Tags: c#, wpf, file

For example, lets say I have a text file with one line of code named Template.txt included in the project folder.

Since the text file is included with the project, is there another way to specify this file or would I still have to specify the full file path?

Answer (score 1):

If it's included in the project and if you select the option `copy always` from the property `Copy to Output Directory` (Right click on the file and select properties in `VS`), you will have the file available in the `bin/` folder after compilation. So, you would not need the entire path. Just the name of the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question,
you can put the file on the same folder where the exe file is and specify only the name of the file [Template.txt].